# The size of a PE Header

Tags: windows, portable-executable

Is there a way to find out the size of a PE Header without reading all of it or the entire file?

Comment: This is a good reference for understanding the overall PE format and how its size could be calculated: https://wiki.osdev.org/PE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can calculate the total size of the PE header like this:

```
sizeof(Signature) + sizeof(FileHeader) + sizeof(OptionalHeader) + sizeof(SectionTable)
```

The file header always has the same size but the OptionalHeader's size can differ, as can the section table size.

The OptionalHeader's size is stored in `FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader`, and the section table size equals `FileHeader.NumberOfSections * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)`

And some C code:

```
DWORD SizeOfPEHeader(const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * pNTH)
{
    return (offsetof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, OptionalHeader) + pNTH->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader + (pNTH->FileHeader.NumberOfSections * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)));
}
```

All you have to do is read the DOS header, get the PE offset (e_lfanew) and read PE.Signature + PE.FileHeader into memory. That's two reading operations of fixed size and you have all the info you need.

Comment: This will be off by quite a bit. It's not considering the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER e_lfanew offset. If you add sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) size to it, it will probably be correct most of the time. But the correct way would be to pass the image base (instead of PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) and then add to that formula ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) base)->e_lfanew.

Comment: @Sirmabus That would give you the combined size of the DOS header + the DOS binary + the PE header. Depending on your use case that might be what you want, my answer was about the PE header alone.